# Multiplication is returning me incorrect values

Tags: c++, arduino

I am writing some code for an Arduino project I am working on, and the multiplication is returning me incorrect values, and I can't figure out why.

```
String calculateShutterSpeed(float fs, int i, int l){
float fstop = fs;
int iso = i;
int lux = l;
float c = 1.00;
float shutterspeedTop = 0;
double shutterspeedBottom = 0;

shutterspeedTop = pow(fs, 2)*c;
shutterspeedBottom = lux*iso;

shutterspeedBottom = shutterspeedBottom/shutterspeedTop;
```

The code giving me the error is the line where I multiply lux by iso, in some cases (with small numbers) it works fine, but as soon as I use larger numbers it starts giving me incorrect numbers, such as a lux of 4833 and iso of 200 will give me a result of -16440.

Comment: The range of an `int` on Arduino is -32768 to 32767. Easy fix is to change `iso` and `lux` from `int` to `double`.

Comment: why so many parenthesis ?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what board you have, the [size of an int](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/) will be either two or four bytes.

Multiplying two 2-byte integers together produces another 2-byte integer and, when too large for the range, [overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow); this is the behavior you're seeing.

You'll have to go to a [`long`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/long/) or, might as well, a [`double`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/double/).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried to change to a double, and it fixed my problem, and it works for a greater range, but it still breaks for larger numbers (lux values of 10,000). Are there any other ways to fix this?

Comment: If you want arbitrary precision integers, you'll need to implement 'big numbers' or use a bignum library.

Comment: Oops, realized after some investigation the new problem was not in the size, so thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

An `int` type can hold numbers up to a limit.
In your case that seems to be 2^16 = 65536 numbers which means you can have numbers in range [-32,768, 32,767].
You can use `long` type to resolve the problem.

Quick note:
`short` = 2-byte
`long`  = 4-byte
`int`   = 2-byte or 4-byte (depending on architecture)

*Thanks to ChiefTwoPencils for pointing out ambiquity!*

Comment: Suggest using fixed-width type, e.g. `uint32_t` for 32-bit values